# Android Airplane Mode - Different API versions

Tags: android, api, version

Can somebody tell me how to handle this situation. I am aware that with API 17, testing for airplane mode has been moved from `Setting.System` to `Settings.Global`. Knowing that many of the users will be on phones using the older api, but wanting to handle the deprecation correctly, I've written the following method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

    try {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
          Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }   
}
```

The problem is that in my manifest, I've set the minSDK value to 9, which is where I want it. The conflict is that then I get this error:

`Call requires API level 17 (current min is 9)`

What is the correct way to handle this type of situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check which version the user has

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLYBEAN){

}else{

}
```

then just suppress the lint error

Comment: Thanks. Is that the usual method for handling API code deprecation? I've never been much of a fan of suppressing error messages since it seems like kind of a brute force approach.

Comment: that is what you do, its just an error to make sure you handle it, the project wont build unless you suppress it